# Movie with character able to take a "god form" with blue skin and animal head

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie was probably late 1990s early 2000. The movie had a main character who was guarding a child he was able to take a "god form" of blue skin with an animal head.  Sorry I have no other info.

Comment: "MC"? like Master of Ceremonies?

Comment: MC as in main character

Comment: Again this was so long ago I'm lacking any other information

Comment: No other information? Was the guarded child a boy or a girl, 1 year old or 15 years or old? Was the setting urban or rural? Contemporary, medieval, futuristic? Was the main character armed with a sword, pistol, submachine gun, magic wand, blaster?

Comment: Urban contemporary child was between 10 and 12. Urban  think an advanced future.

Comment: Was this live-action or animated?

Answer (score 7):

This has similarities with 'Immortal', a French film [IMDB Entry](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0314063/?ref_=kw_li_tt)

> In the distant future, Earth is occupied by ancient gods and
> genetically altered humans. When a god is sentenced to death he seeks
> a new human host and a woman to bear his child.

The film has a god-like character which has an eagle like head.

[More on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortal_(2004_film))

> The film takes place in New York City in late 21 century, where
> genetically altered humans live side by side with unaltered men and
> women, and where Central Park has been mysteriously encased in an
> "intrusion zone" where people who attempt to enter are instantly
> killed. A strange pyramid has appeared over the city; inside, the gods
> of ancient Egypt have judged Horus, one of their fellow gods, to cease
> his immortality.
>
> In the city below, Jill, a young woman with blue hair, is arrested.
> She is not completely human; her tissues appear to be no more than a
> few months old according to an examining physician, although her
> physical form is already that of an adult. She also possesses a number
> of secret powers, including one that enables her to procreate with
> gods, though she knows nothing of this. Horus is given a limited time
> to interact with the humans of New York and procreate. During his
> search for a host body, Horus encounters Nikopol, a rebel condemned to
> 30 years of hibernation who, due to a mechanical accident, escapes his
> prison one year early.
>
> Horus has been unsuccessful in attempting to take over the bodies of
> other humans; due to an incompatibility with the genetic alterations
> humans have undergone, the host bodies self-destruct while attempting
> to accommodate a god. Nikopol's body is acceptable as it has been
> frozen in prison/storage and not undergone the genetic changes causing
> the rejections. Horus takes partial control of Nikopol's body and
> starts looking for a woman he can mate with to provide him a son
> before his death sentence is carried out. When Horus/Nikopol discovers
> Jill, they become entangled in a web of murder and intrigue.

[image: The god-like animal form]

Comment: You can watch it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzHJf-am0QY&t=94m10s At the end, the child shows up and can take the shape of a hawk, like his father.